# Convert with date time format wc_last login

Tags: wordpress, date, datetime, woocommerce

I want to convert wc_last_login with value 1657324800 to format Y-m-d.
if I use human_time_diff it show time like 2 days ago or 2 month ago.
I want to get exact date.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
$last_active = get_user_meta($customer->ID, 'wc_last_active', true); 
echo $new_date_format = date('Y-m-d', $last_active);
```